A problem of palindromic numbers in number theory
In the decimal system, the number
$[ a = a_{n} \times 10^{n} + a_{n-1} \times 10^{n-1} + \cdots + a_{i} \times 10^{i} + \cdots + a_{1} \times 10^{1} + a_{0} ]$
where $( a_{n}, a_{n-1}, \cdots, a_{i}, \cdots, a_{1}, a_{0} \in \{0, 1, 2, 3, \cdots, 9\} )$ and$( a_{n} \neq 0 )$, is defined as the 'inverse (inverse) ordinal' of
$[ \bar{a} = a_{0} \times 10^{n} + a_{1} \times 10^{n-1} + \cdots + a_{i} \times 10^{n-i} + \cdots + a_{n-1} \times 10^{1} + a_{n} ]$
(i.e., $(\bar{a})$ has the same number of digits $( n )$ of $( a )$, allowing $( a_{0} = 0 $), but the order of the digits in $(\bar{a})$ is the opposite of that in $( a )$), e.g., the inverse of 2024 is 4202, and the inverse of 2030 is 0302 (i.e., 302).
Find (or determine) all positive integers ( n ) such that both of the following conditions are satisfied:

The numbers $\frac{9 \cdot n - 5}{41}$ and $\frac{41 \cdot n - 6}{59}$ are both positive integers.
The number $(\frac{9 \cdot n - 5}{41} + \frac{41 \cdot n - 6}{59})$ is exactly the 'inverse' of the number $(\frac{9 \cdot n - 5}{41})$.
My idea is let:
$[ k = \frac{9n - 5}{41} ]$
$[ m = \frac{41n - 6}{59} ]$
$ n = \frac{41k + 5}{9},n = \frac{59m + 6}{41},k = -2718 + 531t 1681k - 531m = -151,m = -14647 + 1681t$ ,but how to do next?


This question is not related to palindromic numbers, which in this context are their own inverse.
